# update SQL in python with %s

Tags: python

```
SQL_Querry = ('UPDATE jeu SET %s = %s WHERE Nom = %s')
SQL_Data = (valeur1, valeur2, nom)
cursor.execute(SQL_Querry, SQL_Data)`

# this line works
    SQL_Querry = ("UPDATE jeu SET Intelligence = %s WHERE Nom = %s")
# this one not
    SQL_Querry = ("UPDATE jeu SET 'Intelligence' = %s WHERE Nom = %s")
```

I launch the function like this

```
Update_Base('Intelligence', 10, 'Didier')
```

The proble is the `'` the variable put autamically in the SQL field, do you know how can I avoid the problem

```
SQL_Querry = ("UPDATE jeu SET Intelligence = %s WHERE Nom = %s")
```

Comment: you can't use a placeholder for a column name, only for values.